# InvalidUseOfMatchersException when mocking datasource

Tags: mockito

```java
@Test
public void getRelationInteractionDataTest() throws Exception {
    InteractionData iData = new InteractionData();
    when(mockJdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).thenReturn(dataSource);
    relationshipCheckDaoImpl.getRelationInteractionData(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
}
```

```
Exception:failed with = org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

Comment: Hi @Avinash, please add more details about your problem to give us more details what you want and how can we help with. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
relationshipCheckDaoImpl.getRelationInteractionData(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
```

While it may sound alluring to test a method with 'any' parameter, no, this isn't what matchers are for. Use actual values instead:

```
relationshipCheckDaoImpl.getRelationInteractionData("a", "b");
```

The reason is: You can use matchers when preparing a mock method...

```
Mockito.when( a.doB( Mockito.anyString() ) ).thenReturn("XYZ";
```

...or when verifying that something was called...

```
Mockito.verify( a ).doB( Mockito.anyString() );
```

...but not when calling the method itself, since what should the matchers match there? This will only confuse Mockito's internal system.